# How do I learn higher level versions of hunter arts?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Each weapon has several hunter arts. I know from progressing through the offline quests that you unlock new ones via the main game, but how do you unlock higher level versions of the same art?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/4u6yd0/hunter_art_unlock_quests/ to be useful.

I can't speak to the accuracy of every line, but it's been true for the Charge Blade skills.

Comment: Great find, but consider summarizing it to prevent link rot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep doing more quests. I got a higher level version of an existing art that way. I don't think there's any special condition for it.

Comment: I think specifically it's Village Request quests and urgent quests.